# Plastic coating defect in electrical wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

Below is a close up photo of one of the hot wires to my dryer. Recently several of my outlets and one bank of lights went out; no breakers were tripped. Then the dryer quit heating, but will turn on and still tumble.

A multimeter check of the dryer outlet gave me a nice 240 - 245 on the two hot holes, but varied between 0 and 120 when used on one hot hole and the neutral, or one hot hole and the ground. Mostly on the 0 side, I had to really wiggle and play with the probe to get it higher than that.  I have been tracing circuits via a circuit tracer and by turning off breakers and noting which outlets and lights went out so that I have a sense of what to tell the electrician.

The circuit tracer goes nuts when I use it (indicates that every breaker is attached to every outlet), which drove me to finally inspecting the wiring closer.

My guess is that this wire - which is confirmed to go to the dryer - has split its cover on the back and is in contact with a grounding wire or 3 on the backside of it. That would explain the lack of heat to the dryer. Would that be in line with what more experienced individuals see as a possibility?

[image: Wires in split sheathing passing behind a metal frame]

Comment: `My guess is that this wire - which is confirmed to go to the dryer - has split its cover on the back` ... why are you guessing?

Comment: How about some pictures from further back.

Comment: The other hot slot reads a steady 120 to neutral correct?

Comment: *Recently several of my outlets and one bank of lights went out* - What voltage do you get on those outlets? Does the voltage vary when you turn the dryer on? Does anything change if the dyer is *unplugged*?

Comment: By itself that doesn’t look unusual at all. High-current building wiring is a fairly thin outer covering around the individual large conductors. It’s normal to be able to see the shape of the inner wires especially when the cable bends to make a turn.